# Show Y-Axis ticks from -1 to 1

Tags: matlab, plot, subplot

I am writing a Matlab script to plot a regular sine wave with a frequency of 5Hz sampled every .01 second. I am trying to achieve this..

[image: Ticks showing from -1 to 1 without all the intermediary ticks in between]

But I am gettting this..

[image: My result with it showing ticks at every .2]

I just want my graph to show -1 to 1.

Here is the matlab code...

```
% Script that will show stem plots of a sine wave with a frequency of 
% 5Hz sampled every .01 seconds.

time = [0:.01:0.5]; % Sampling time 0 - 10 seconds at a rate of .01 second
frequency = 5; % The frequency is 5 Hz
samplingFrequency = .01;
fc = frequency/samplingFrequency;

sineWave = sin(2*pi*frequency*time);

figure(1)
plot(time, sineWave);

figure(2)
stem(time, sineWave, ':r');
```

Please any clue on how to achieve this would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the problem? The `y`-axis is going between `-1` and `1`, and the `x`-axis is between `0` and `0.5`. What is the problem?

Comment: Sorry that is what I mean the Y-Axis. @David

Comment: The `y`-axis is going between `-1` and `1`. I don't see the problem?

Comment: Yes, the first figure is how I want it. The second is how I have it I dont want the -.02 and .02, etc just the -1 and 1. Does that explain it a little better? @David

Comment: Right, you just want your graph to show -1 *and* 1, not -1 *to* 1. Pursuit's answer is what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking how to remove the extra ticks on the Y axis, you can use this:

```
set(gca,'ytick',[-1 0 1]);
```

Otherwise, I think that we'll need more description.

Comment: Yes, I want to remove the .2, .4, .6, etc and the negative values as well. Where would I place this piece of code? @Pursuit

Comment: @diaz994 Place it after `plot` / `stem`, that is, once the graph has been drawn

Comment: Awesome, that got rid of that. thank you. Now that I have that would you happen to know how to make the stem plot with continuous line instead of dashes?

Comment: @diaz994 replace the `':r'` line specifier by `'r'`.

Comment: Great, thanks. So if you do the graphs in a subplot() then it automatically takes away the subticks between -1 and 1. So that was pretty cool. If you do the graphs stand alone then you have to use set(gca, 'ytick', [-1 0 1]);

Comment: If you don't specify where you want the ticks, it actually tries to place them with an appropriate spacing given the since of the plot. The important thing I'd the size, not if it is a subplot or not.